# How to send diffrent order emails to admin and customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, sales, transactional-mail

I would like to send different emails to both customer and admin. I have two email templates `New Order` and `Admin Order`.

And I am setting the template on `System->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails->Order`

Here I can assign only one email template. I would like to send two email template to both customer and admin.

[image]

I want to send diffrent emails to both customer and support@example.com . How to achieve this ?

Comment: According to your settings, new order mail goes to customer and support@exmple.com. If you need add another email, then add to 'support@exmple.com,support1@exmple.com,support2@exmple.com'

Comment: @SohelRana I would like to email to support@example.com and the user. The issue is that I want to send two different emails for each user, not the same content

Comment: @VinodVT Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override Magento Sales module functionality to create a second email template and send it to admin using custom code.

Alternatively, if you are searching for a pre-made module, then have a look at [this module](https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_AdminOrderNotifier).

I have used it for one of my clients and it works fine.