# How to send different order emails to admin and customer in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, transactional-mail

I want to send different transnational mail template for admin and customer. I know Magento gives the functionality for the CC transactional mail template. But in my case I want a different mail template for the administrator. So i want to create the functionality for the different mail template for the customer and admin after placing the order.

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131275/how-to-send-diffrent-order-emails-to-admin-and-customer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa     
Please see this link i want same functionality for magento 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try pre-made extensions like:

- https://www.hiddentechies.com/new-order-notification-magento-2.html (Free)
- https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-2-new-order-notification/19237122 (Paid)

or you can create a simple module, in which you may make use of **observer** or **plugin** feature of Magento 2 and write custom code to send additional email with your own template to the admin user.

**Update: Modifications needed in some files as requested by @AkashPatel**

**File:** app/code/Hiddentechies/Neworder/Observer/NewOrder.php

You can see that in the execute function, there are only admin_subject and cur_order_id are being passed as vars.

```
$vars = [
           'admin_subject' => $subject,
           'cur_order_id' => "#".$orderIncId,
        ];
```

You need to get more data in the observer function and pass it to the $vars array. Then you would need to get and show those vars in the following file.

```
app/code/Hiddentechies/Neworder/view/frontend/email/new_order_email.html
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: I have installed extension it's working for simple mail template but when i load new order template its not working.Please see the screen shot.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3416086/e717cf132490b50f7a869c6252a12d10

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand. Can you please explain a bit more about your problem?

Comment: Generally if we want to add custom template for suppose new order functionality then we customize it and assign it from admin side. so i follow the same procedure.

My Client requirement is he wants two different mail for customer order and merchant order confirmation.

So i have installed one extension which you gave me. What i do is create a copy of sales order template in my custom template and assign it from admin. but when i place order in my mail(merchent mail) only get static data i dont get any dynamic data like "Billing Address and all"
as per screen shot.

Comment: @AkashPatel, Since the module is available free, it has limited features. You need to modify some functionality. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: How to pass the order item table (order review table) in the $var array? sales_email_order_item does not work if i put this code directly in the mail template.

Comment: As per my point of view, You may draw HTML for the order items section in the controller and assign it to a variable. Then get the value of variable and print in template directly.

Comment: Mohit Kumar Arora, I have used the above mentioned extension but it is not working for me in the magento commerce edition.Please help.

Comment: @MeetaliGupta, I have not tried it for the commerce edition Magento. I think you can try it for the open source edition first and if it works, you may need to make minor changes to make it work for the commerce edition.

Comment: It is working for the open source edition. I can't get the changes which I need to do for the commerce edition.

Comment: Have you checked the logs when you are checking for the commerce edition?